# Concatenation of m4a files is either too long or too short

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to concatenate two `m4a` files, one 20:49 long and the other 10:23 long. Following [this page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate), the first option is:

```
ffmpeg -i 'concat:file1.m4a|file2.m4a' -c copy output.m4a
```

It only processes the first file, e.g. standard output shows:

```
size=   10921kB time=00:20:48.69
```

and the output file is 20 minutes like the first file.

The second option is:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.m4a
```

where `mylist.txt` is:

```
file 'file1.m4a'
file 'file2.m4a'
```

This command uses both files, as standard output shows:

```
size=   16339kB time=00:33:56.73
```

but the duration is wrong, as it should be 31:42. Furthermore, the output file has duration 32:06 when played from the operating system (macOS).

How can I get FFMPEG to concatenate two files respecting their duration?

Comment: Using `-c copy` from `m4a` to `mp3` is bound to produce nonsense.

Comment: You're right, it was my mistake in copying commands. I edited the question. I had problems in converting to mp3 with libmp3lame, then changed the commands to only m4a for simplicity. In fact, that command you mention fails in my `ffmpeg`  with `Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument`.

Comment: If it is all m4a, then the problem is a bit more complex: m4a contains timecodes, which may or may not start at zero. The `concat` demuxer is notorious for not considering this. In broadcast we allways convert to raw PCM (or something else that has not timestamps), then concat, then create the final output format. Along the lines of `ffmpeg -i file1,m4a -c:a pcm_s16le -f s16le file1.pcm ; ffmpeg -i file2,m4a -c:a pcm_s16le -f s16le file2.pcm ; cat file2.pcm >> file1.pcm ; ffmpeg -f s16le -i file1.pcm -c:a aac -b:a whatever -ac whatever output.m4a`

Comment: I can do the conversion to PCM alright and I believe `cat` is just appending the two files. I am getting errors with the last command and I cannot find `-b` in the manual. Can you give examples of the `whatever` in the last line?

Comment: `-b:a` sets the audio bandwidth. Something like `-b:a 96k` (or 192k) might be a good starting point, `-ac` defines the number of audio channels, so `-ac 2` works for stereo. You are right, that `cat`just appends the file - this is a big advantage of raw PCM (as opposed to .wav).

Comment: Yes, this works! Would you like to write an answer so I accept it?

Comment: By the way, I realized that one of the files had a different duration in the original m4a and in the output of the m4a-PCM-m4a conversion. I asked about it [here](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/44982/audio-file-in-shorter-in-m4a-than-in-pcm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenation of files is sometimes not very intuitive - this is due to the fact, that many formats contain timestamps, that may or may not start at zero, be continuous etc., depending on the creation and editing history of that file.

This is one of the reasons, why in the broadcast world formats rule, that can just be concatenated: MPEGTS (with the need to have an eye on continuity counters) or RAW (raw PCM resp. raw h.264).

If reencoding is an option I recommend you convert your original files to raw PCM, along the lines of

```
ffmpeg -i file1.m4a -c:a pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 48000 -f s16le file1.pcm
ffmpeg -i file2.m4a -c:a pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 48000 -f s16le file2.pcm
```

This will create 2 raw PCM files, with 2 channels (Stereo, `-ac 2`) each and a sample rate of 48KHz (`-ar 48000`)

You can now concatenate those files, e.g. via `cat file2.pcm >> file1.pcm` - this creates a new raw representation of the file with no timestamps, just the plain audio samples.

To reencode the result into AAC, you go along the lines of

```
ffmpeg -f s16le -ac 2 -ar 48000 -i file1.pcm -c:a aac -b:a 192K -ac 2 output.m4a
```

Let's break this down:

- First I tell ffmpeg to open a file of format raw PCM (signed 16bit low endian `-f s16le`) containing 2 audio channels (`-ac 2`) of 48KHz sample rate (`-ar 48000`) and stored in file1.pcm (as usual with ffmpeg, the order of the parameters is important)
- then to reencode with AAC (`-c:a`) and a bandwidth of 192Kbit/s (`-ba:a`) again in stereo (`-ac 2`)